# SQL query, date functions

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

[image: Table schema]

I need to find the "CF" of the people who have `Data_Iscrizione<(Current Data-5 years)`.

```
SELECT U.CF
FROM utente AS U
WHERE ???
```

I've tried to use `DATEDIFF`, `DATE_SUB`, `CURRENT_DATE` and everything I've found on the Internet, but I'm not able to make it work. Any advice?

Comment: where is your table?

Comment: can you explain your requirement with sample data set

Comment: sorry the table is there https://i.gyazo.com/71c469f740bbc7489d74bb87f732ec72.png

Answer (score 0):

You would use `date_sub()`:

```
where Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year)
```

Comment: I get this error https://i.gyazo.com/902bffbf062e897619a0d51865a3d00c.png

Comment: @LucaPearl . . . That should be "year" not "years".